# Why is it when I use background: url() my image never shows?

Tags: css, background

I have spent way to long trying to figure out why my code isn't executing the background: url() correctly. My image "beardlawyer.jpg" is in the same folder as my html and css file.

Things I've tried already:

```
background: url("/Best Lawyer Website/beardlawyer.jpg");

background: url('beardlawyer.jpg');

background: url(/beardlawyer.jpg);

background: url('/beardlawyer.jpg);
```

And to be honest I don't understand why people either use the ' mark or the " inside the parentheses.

actual html

```
<section id="showcase">
        <div class="container">
            <h1> Experienced lawyers at a moments notice </h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

The CSS at the moment

```
#showcase {
    min-height: 200px;
    background:url("/Best Lawyer Website/beardlawyer.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`background-image`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) and specify a width and height on the element.

```css
#showcase {
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/random");
}
```

```html
<div id="showcase"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah this doesn't seem to work either. I checked spelling very carefully too. I can't seem to see what's going wrong.

Comment: It must be for some thing else wrong like the location of your image. Try this image URL to test it https://source.unsplash.com/random.

Comment: Yeah not even that is working. I am fairly new to coding so bear with me, but when trying to test out that url would I use something like this: ```background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556815917-a896d1aaf40a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9");```

Comment: I've updated my answer. Just copy my code above. You can see it working in the snippet too.

Comment: So in the instance where it's still not working on my end, what can that possibly mean? It works fine in the snippet so it's definitely not the code.

Comment: Wow so I opened this code in another browser (mozilla firefox) and it worked perfectly. I have been working in google chrome this whole time. Why is the html and css compatible with mozilla firefox and not google chrome?

Comment: It could just be caching. Try pressing Ctrl + F5 in Chrome to clear the cache and load the latest version of your code. Or even just open an incognito window and run it there as there is no cache in incognito mode.